# ArcGIS: Splitting Street Full Street Name into Street Name and Street Name Post Type

Tags: arcpy, schema-architecture, schema

Our team is starting to implement NG 9-1-1 and as [NENA Standards for GIS Data Model](https://cdn.ymaws.com/www.nena.org/resource/resmgr/standards/nena-sta-006.2-2022_ng9-1-1_.pdf) have the fields laid out (referencing pages 24-25 &  30-31). The St_Name (Street Name) and St_PosType (Street Name Post Type) are separated fields.

Our current schema for both our Road Centerlines and Address Points have our Street Name & Street Name Post Type as a single field called FULLNAME (Full Road Name), see [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef0de.jpg).

We are trying to find the best way to separate our FULLNAME field into two fields based on the NENA Standards.

Another speedbump is the fact that some of the Street Name post types are not in the approved [USPS Street Suffix Abbreviations](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm). I.e. instead of BLVD we have BL or instead of CIR we have CR. (This is supposedly due to limitations within another software we use, but I'm willing to break that software to get in compliance with NENA as well as make our data look prettier).

I believe the best way to approach this would be using a dictionary and an UpdateCursor, but I am quite rusty on my Python skills.

Comment: Looking at your image, I have doubts "CR" is a replacement for "CIR" because `CR 226` sure seems more like "County Road 226" rather than "Circle 226".

Comment: That is correct, CR does correspond to County Road. CIR is the Street Name Post Type of certain streets [here is a list for example](https://imgur.com/a/9KDF1cu). CIR is a bad example because I just realized that CIR is the approved [USPS Street Suffix Abbreviation](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm). A better example is the list of roads that are [BL instead of BLVD](https://imgur.com/a/Pqz9MH0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you off to a pretty good start... also takes into account the directionals (N, S, NE, etc...)

```
import arcpy

# Create a dictionary of directionals
dict_directionals = {}
dict_directionals["N"]  = "NORTH"
dict_directionals["S"]  = "SOUTH"
dict_directionals["E"]  = "EAST"
dict_directionals["W"]  = "WEST"
dict_directionals["NE"] = "NORTHEAST"
dict_directionals["NW"] = "NORTHWEST"
dict_directionals["SE"] = "SOUTHEAST"
dict_directionals["SW"] = "SOUTHWEST"


# Create a dictionary of post types
dict_posttypes = {}
dict_posttypes["ST"]    = "STREET"
dict_posttypes["RD"]    = "ROAD"
dict_posttypes["DR"]    = "DRIVE"
dict_posttypes["AVE"]   = "AVENUE"
dict_posttypes["BL"]    = "BOULEVARD"
dict_posttypes["CR"]    = "CIRCLE"
# ADD MORE HERE AS NEEDED...


# Create feature layer for your feature class 
path_centerlines = "C:/YourFolder/YourCounty.gdb/Dataset/Centerlines"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path_centerlines, "lyr_Centerlines")

# Add fields as needed
if "NEW_St_PreDir" not in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("lyr_Centerlines")]:
    arcpy.AddField_management("lyr_Centerlines", "NEW_St_PreDir", "TEXT", "", "", "9")

if "NEW_St_Name" not in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("lyr_Centerlines")]:
    arcpy.AddField_management("lyr_Centerlines", "NEW_St_Name", "TEXT", "", "", "254")

if "NEW_St_PosTyp" not in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("lyr_Centerlines")]:
    arcpy.AddField_management("lyr_Centerlines", "NEW_St_PosTyp", "TEXT", "", "", "50")

if "NEW_St_PosDir" not in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("lyr_Centerlines")]:
    arcpy.AddField_management("lyr_Centerlines", "NEW_St_PosDir", "TEXT", "", "", "9")

# Create an Update Cursor
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("lyr_Centerlines", ["FullRoadName", "NEW_St_PreDir", "NEW_St_Name", "NEW_St_PosTyp", "NEW_St_PosDir"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # First, split the FullStreetName into separate parts
        parts = row[0].split(' ')

        # If the last part is a directional, populate the "NEW_StPosDir" field with the directional, then remove the part
        if len(parts) > 1 and parts[-1] in dict_directionals.keys():
            row[4] = dict_directionals[parts[-1]]
            parts.pop(-1)
            
        # If the first part is a directional, populate the "NEW_StPreDir" field with the directional, then remove the part
        if len(parts) > 1 and parts[0] in dict_directionals.keys():
            row[1] = dict_directionals[parts[0]]
            parts.pop(0)
            
        # What's left now should be only parts that contain the street name and street type

        # If the last part is now a street type, populate the "NEW_St_PosTyp" field, then remove the last part
        if len(parts) > 1 and parts[-1] in dict_posttypes.keys():
            row[3] = dict_posttypes[parts[-1]]
            parts.pop(-1)

        # What's left now should only be the street name
        row[2] = ' '.join(parts)

        # Update the row
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, all I had to do was create a conditional for the <Null> and blank values before splitting the FullStreetName into separate parts:     for row in cursor:
        # First, split the FULLNAME into separate parts
        if row[0]:
            parts = row[0].split(' ')
        else:
            print("there are null values in your data")